# Python installing packages SSL error in VS2019

Tags: python, package, ssl-certificate

I'm new to Python, when I'm installing or updating packages in Visual Studio 2019 I'm getting following error message. How can I fix it?

```
-- -- - Installing 'pip'-- -- -
  Collecting pip == 20.0 .2
WARNING: Retrying(Retry(total = 4, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None, status = None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain(_ssl.c: 1076)
'))': /simple/pip /
WARNING: Retrying(Retry(total = 3, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None, status = None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain(_ssl.c: 1076)
'))': /simple/pip /
WARNING: Retrying(Retry(total = 2, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None, status = None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain(_ssl.c: 1076)
'))': /simple/pip /
WARNING: Retrying(Retry(total = 1, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None, status = None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain(_ssl.c: 1076)
'))': /simple/pip /
WARNING: Retrying(Retry(total = 0, connect = None, read = None, redirect = None, status = None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, ' [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain(_ssl.c: 1076)
'))': /simple/pip /
Could not fetch URL https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip == 20.0 .2(from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found
for pip == 20.0 .2
Could not fetch URL https: //pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  -- -- - Failed to install 'pip'-- -- -
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: this answer does not solve my problem. I would like to know how to address this in VS2019?

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52006563/11327778